# Sharepoint 2010 and CMIS Producer authentication issue

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, cmis

I have an application that integrates with content systems like Alfresco and IBM FileNet P8. We have an SP 2010 system I need to integrate. The SP system is secured via Claims-based authentication and the CMIS Producer has been added to the 2010 server. What I find is that, unless I enable Basic Authentication, neither my app nor other tools, such as CMIS Workbench, can connect.

As an example, I attempt the following:

```
Dim ws As WS_CMIS.RepositoryServicePortClient = Nothing
ws = New WS_CMIS.RepositoryServicePortClient(endpointConfigurationName:=endpointConfigurationName)

ws.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = MyUserName
ws.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = MyPassword

DropDownListQuery.Items.Clear()

For Each rep As WS_CMIS.cmisRepositoryEntryType In ws.getRepositories(Nothing)
  DropDownListQuery.Items.Add(rep.repositoryId)
Next
```

But, when I issue the ws.getRepositories, I get a 401 auth error. This code works just fine for Alfresco, FileNet, and the like.

The endpointConfigurationName points to this entry in the web.config's system.servicemodel.client section:

```
endpoint name="RepositoryServicePortSP" address="http://avs-sharep2013/sites/Sandbox1/_vti_bin/cmis/soap/RepositoryService.svc" 
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RepositoryServicePortBindingSP" contract="WS_CMIS.RepositoryServicePort"/>
```

The bindingConfiguration (in system.service.model.bindings.basicHttpBinding), looks like this:

```
  <binding name="RepositoryServicePortBindingSP" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="1048576" maxBufferPoolSize="1048576" maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576"
      messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="Default Realm" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
  </binding>
```

I am a relative rookie at WCF configuration, so my guess is my answer is in modifying the configuration of endpoint and binding.

On the other hand, one of the replies I have gotten back on a SharePoint forum site suggests SP 2010 may support only limited forms of authentication to the CMIS Producer:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72988/sharepoint-2010-cmis-integration-and-claims-based-authentication

Any one have experience with using SharePoint and the CMIS Producer with anything other than Basic and Digest authentication?

And, if so, any help/pointers on how to configure the WCF settings above would be wildly appreciated.

Thanks